# jenkins container without root authority

Tags: linux, bash, maven, jenkins

I run a docker container by

> [root@compute maven]# docker run -d -p 8083:8080 --name jenkins -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /root/maven-tar/:/root  csphere/jenkins:1.609 
>   e40f704478e5e37ee3f214a1469f5851a78c324099610a12e79238b8599e194a

Then I get into the container by "docker exec"

> [root@compute maven]# docker exec -it jenkins /bin/bash
>
> jenkins@e40f704478e5:

I try run "docker ps",it showes this

> jenkins@e40f704478e5:/$ docker ps
>
> /usr/bin/docker: 2: .: Can't open /etc/sysconfig/docker

Comment: Well is the file there?

Comment: yes,the file is there. if i use docker exec -it -u root jenkins /bin/bash ,then i can successful execute the command 'docker ps',but ,that's not what i actually want.i need to execute this command with a anonymous user.it mean anyone who exec into this container can execute this command.but it seems never happend

Comment: So you have another docker daemon running inside the docker container you are connecting to?

Comment: not exactly,it is actually the docker daemon of the host server(vps),i just use docker -v to mount the docker.sock into the container.